# Procedure or function Usp_InsertPostJob has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I have created the page to post the job, after click on add button I am getting this exception

> Procedure or function Usp_InsertPostJob has too many arguments specified.

[image]

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

public partial class Profile_Employer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    Int32 rowCount = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {


      bindOpeningType();
      bindJobProfile();
      bindSkills();

      if (Session["UserName"] != null)
      {
         lblUserName.Text = Session["UserName"].ToString();
      }
      else
      {
          Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
      }
   }
}

protected void btnPostJob_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Usp_InsertPostJob", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Opening_Type", ddlOpeningType.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job_Description", txtJobDescription.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job_Profile", ddlJobProfile.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No_Of_Opening", Convert.ToInt32(txtNoOfOpening.Text.Trim()));

                string itemList = string.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i < lstboxRequiredSkills.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (lstboxRequiredSkills.Items[i].Selected == true || lstboxRequiredSkills.Items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        itemList += lstboxRequiredSkills.Items[i].ToString() + ", ";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Required_Skills", itemList);
                    }
                }

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Required_Experiance", txtRequiredExp.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Interview_Date", Convert.ToDateTime(txtInterviewDate.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Interview_Time", txtTime.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Venue", txtVenue.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hr_Name", txtHrName.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hr_Mobile", Convert.ToDecimal(txtHrMobile.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hr_Email", txtHrEmail.Text.Trim().ToLower());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"].ToString().Trim()));
                rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rowCount == 1)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Operation success!')</script>");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROC Usp_InsertPostJob

    @Opening_Type varchar(20),
    @Job_Description varchar(500),
    @Job_Profile varchar(50),
    @No_Of_Opening int=0,
    @Required_Skills varchar(500),
    @Required_Experiance varchar(10),
    @Interview_Date datetime,
    @Interview_Time varchar (50),
    @Venue varchar (500),
    @Hr_Name varchar (100),
    @Hr_Mobile decimal (10),
    @Hr_Email nvarchar (max),
    @CreatedBy int=0

AS

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Post_Job(Opening_Type,Job_Description,Job_Profile,No_Of_Opening,Required_Skills,Required_Experiance,Interview_Date,Interview_Time,Venue,Hr_Name,Hr_Mobile,Hr_Email,CreatedBy)
    VALUES(@Opening_Type,@Job_Description,@Job_Profile,@No_Of_Opening,@Required_Skills,@Required_Experiance,@Interview_Date,@Interview_Time,@Venue,@Hr_Name,@Hr_Mobile,@Hr_Email,@CreatedBy)

END
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Post_Job](
    [JobId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Opening_Type] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Job_Description] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Job_Profile] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [No_Of_Opening] [int] NULL,
    [Required_Skills] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Required_Experiance] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Interview_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Interview_Time] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Venue] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Hr_Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hr_Mobile] [decimal](10, 0) NULL,
    [Hr_Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit]  DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime]  DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedOn] [datetime] NULL
)
```

Comment: You should not store anything as comma separated list. That will make searching the data a lot more difficult then. You have other issues with your database design too, for example you're storing a date as datetime (which as time already) and then you have a time field that's varchar(30).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You placed "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Required_Skills", itemList);" inside a loop. Change your code to:

```
string itemList = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < lstboxRequiredSkills.Items.Count; i++)
{
  if (lstboxRequiredSkills.Items[i].Selected == true || lstboxRequiredSkills.Items.Count > 0)
  {
    itemList += lstboxRequiredSkills.Items[i].ToString() + ", ";   
  }
}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Required_Skills", itemList);
```

Comment: Opps that's the mistake! Thank you!